How to find the precise scale parameter value accurately to precise decimal places in Google Earth Engine
I am training a classifier and results change drastically upon ±.00001 level of zoom precision to get the final trained output.
Is there a way to find out accurate zoom level in which training collection polygons were drawn, so that accurate zoom value can be provided in scale parameter below?
var training_features = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: training_collection,
  properties: ['landcover'],  
  scale: 13.84531
});

Code link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/9381af7611cf2020e9938efe91fd292d
Given below is the difference for scale : 13.84488 and scale : 13.84490 which is quite drastic. The output is more accurate for former value.



It's an interesting observation! but I do have a few questions, what is the original scale of the image you are classifying? and are the used training collection points or other geometries that might overlap several pixels? Ideally, if you can share a toy code to replicate the problem!

@Es_a added code link. I think original scale is around 12 to 13 which i had to zoom slightly back and forth( not too much) , within the area of interest, which is why it’s important in my assumption to get that scale value accurately. i have attached code which has list of rectangular training points.

The correct scale to use should be determined from the input image itself. It's 10 in your case, see the code here https://code.earthengine.google.com/31183f7dd03643b2a8db733c33d6bdfb. However, I think it's interesting as a side question to see how small change in scale led to such large change in results!
